# play file wav j2me - IllegalArgumentException at Manager.createPlayer()

Tags: java-me, midp, mmapi

I got problem about play wav file in my application.

This is my error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(), bci=8
 at Tajwid.Tajwid.run(Tajwid.java:649)
 at Tajwid.Tajwid.actionPerformed(Tajwid.java:186)
 at com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(), bci=19
 at com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:257)
```

This is my code:

> ```
> public void run() {
>     try {
>         InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tes.wav");
>         player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/x-wav");
>
>         player.realize();
>         // get volume control for player and set volume to max
>         vc = (VolumeControl) player.getControl("VolumeControl");
>         if (vc != null) {
>             vc.setLevel(100);
>         }
>         player.prefetch();
>         player.start();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> ```

Device Configuration : CLDC-1.1
Device Profile MIDP 2.0

Comment: What is your problem? Did you get an exception?

Comment: My wav file can't play, what's wrong?

Comment: As your code seems right and assuming you did not get an exception. I think the problem is with your file or with your device (it might not play wav). Please call System.getProperty("audio.encodings") and see what you can play.

Comment: This is my error :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(), bci=8
 at Tajwid.Tajwid.run(Tajwid.java:649)
 at Tajwid.Tajwid.actionPerformed(Tajwid.java:186)
 at com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(), bci=19
 at com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:257)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message you've got has sufficient information to figure what went wrong in the code.

Look at it a bit closer:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
     at javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer()...
```

It says something went wrong in `Manager.createPlayer()`. From your code, it is apparent that you use method `Manager.createPlayer(java.io.InputStream stream, java.lang.String type)`.

If you look into **API documentation** for the method you use ([available online](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#createPlayer%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)), you'll find the explanation when this exception occurs:

```
    Throws:
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Thrown if stream is null.
```

Above means that `stream` parameter (`is` in your code) passed to the method is null.

You could add some logging right after initialization of the `is` to debug this issue easier:

```java
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tes.wav");
// add some logging to see if initialization was OK or not:
System.out.println("input stream is null: [" + (is == null) + "]");
```

That way, when running your MIDlet in emulator, you will see whether `is` was initialized as expected or not.

Actually, looking at the code I would guess that you made a typo in file name passed to getResourceAsStream: **"/tes.wav"** looks like a mis-typed **"/test.wav"**.

Comment: @MuhamadBurhanudin you are welcome. In case if you're interested, you may take a look at [instructions explaining how does accepting an answer work at Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/165773)

Comment: I got answer problem, check here :
[link]http://burhanudin.web.id/programing/java/play-audio-with-j2me[/link]